# Ошибки при парсинге xml через simplexml конвертор в retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, simplexml

Есть XML, который я пытаюсь парсить.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>    
<ValCurs Date="16.10.2021" name="Foreign Currency Market">
    <Valute ID="R01010">
        <NumCode>036</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
        <Value>52,8508</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute ID="R01020A">
        <NumCode>944</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
        <Value>41,9288</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute ID="R01035">
        <NumCode>826</NumCode>
        <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name>
        <Value>97,7729</Value>
    </Valute>

    ...

</ValCurs>
```

По сути, это список с курсом валют.

Я использую следующие pojo

```
@Root(name = "ValCurs", strict = false)
data class ValCurs (
    @field:ElementList(name = "Valute", entry = "Valute", inline = false, required = false)
    var valList: List<Valute>,
    @field:Attribute(name = "Date")
    var date: String,
    @field:Attribute(name = "name")
    var name: String
)

@Root(name="Valute", strict = false)
data class Valute(
    @field:Attribute(name = "ID", required = false)
    var id: String,
    @field:Element(name = "NumCode", required = false)
    var numCode: String,
    @field:Element(name = "CharCode", required = false)
    var charCode: String,
    @field:Element(name = "Nominal", required = false)
    var nominal: String,
    @field:Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    var name: String,
    @field:Element(name = "Value", required = false)
    var value: String
)
```

Но при попытке получения ответа, я все время сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

*"org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class com.pet.moneyconvertor.Valute"*

Что не так я делаю с своими pojo, что мои pojo не соответствуют телу ответа при запросе?

P.S. если убираю , required = false в полях класса Valute(У любого поля), то получаю ошибку:

*"Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=Nominal, required=true, type=void) on field 'nominal' private java.lang.String com.pet.moneyconvertor.Valute.nominal for class com.pet.moneyconvertor.Valute at line -1"*

Если убираю из аннотации элементов и атрибутов @field:, то получаю ошибку:

*"org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter 'Valute' does not have a match in class com.pet.moneyconvertor.ValCurs"*

Ощущение, что мой класс Valute вообще ни разу не соответствует.
Хотя я пытался даже типы данных полей другие указывать, для Nominal -> Int, Value -> Double.

Comment: Понял, что data class в Kotlin не имеет конструктора без параметров, сделал все поля с значением null по умолчанию.
var numCode: String? = null,

в итоге стал получать ошибку 

*"Element 'Valute' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=Valute, inline=false, name=Valute, required=true, type=void) on field 'valList' private java.util.List com.pet.moneyconvertor.ValCurs.valList at line -1"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я потратил на это 2 дня. Надеюсь кому то поможет:

Data class в Kotlin, хоть и удобен, но все же не умеет создавать конструктор по умолчанию без параметров. По этому используя его надо это обязательно учитывать.
Плюс у ElementList при указании entry, вовсе не надо указывать name, а inline нужно наоборот указывать true, так как все элементы списка внутри тэга . Итого подводя итог, я получил следующие pojo:

```
@Root(name = "ValCurs", strict = false)
data class ValCurs(
    @field:ElementList(entry = "Valute", inline = true, required = false)
    var valList: List<Currency>? = null,
    @field:Attribute(name = "Date")
    var date: String? = null,
    @field:Attribute(name = "name")
    var name: String? = null
)


@Root(name="Valute", strict = false)
data class Currency(
    @field:Attribute(name = "ID", required = false)
    var id: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "NumCode", required = false)
    var numCode: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "CharCode", required = false)
    var charCode: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Nominal", required = false)
    var nominal: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    var name: String? = null,
    @field:Element(name = "Value", required = false)
    var value: String? = null
)
```